# string manipulation of Directory structure

Tags: linux, bash, sed, directory-structure

Scenario: I have a script but no idea where I am in the directory tree, I need to resolve back to the nearest known location UPROC[something]

What I have so far:
I have a script running in a directory for example:

```
/home/jim/query/UPROCL/test/bob/dircut.sh
```

now the only constant in this is that the Directory I want will begin with `UPROC`... maybe not `UPROCL` but definitely `UPROC`

So I have written the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

#Absolute path for this script
SCRIPT=$(readlink -f "$0")
echo $SCRIPT

#Gets Path of script without script name
SCRIPTPATH=$(dirname "$SCRIPT")
echo $SCRIPTPATH

#Cuts everything after UPROC(.* is wildcard)/
CUTDOWN=$(sed 's/\(UPROC.*\/\).*/\1/' <<< $SCRIPTPATH)
echo $CUTDOWN
```

The only problem is that it output is:

```
/home/jim/query/UPROCL/test/bob/dircut.sh
/home/jim/query/UPROCL/test/bob
/home/jim/query/UPROCL/test/
```

Can some tell me what is wrong with my sed command as it is not cutting down to

```
/home/jim/query/UPROCL/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `*` is greedy. You want to be more selective about what characters are allowed following "UPROC" -- any non-slash

Not

```
sed 's/\(UPROC.*\/\).*/\1/'
```

but

```
sed -r 's,(UPROC[^/]*/).*,\1,'
```

Using different delimiters for the `s///` command reduces the "leaning toothpick" problem.

Answer (score 1):

Because the `.*` in the `()` is matching to the `/` at the end of `test/`.

You need `[^/]*` instead of `.` to not match any slashes.

Answer (score 1):

When you want to know in which directory you are, why don't use `pwd`?

One thing which might be useful: the command `pwd` shows the value of the environment variable `PWD` (uppercase). In case you want to use the current directory as a value, you might use this.